# What does 'Epoch' mean in training Generative Adversarial Networks

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am training a GAN with text data. When I train the discriminator, I **randomly sample** m positive data from the dataset and generate m negative data with the generator. I found many papers mention about details of implementation such as training epochs. About the training epochs, I have a question about sampling positive data:

1. Sample from the dataset (maybe shuffled) in order, when the whole dataset is covered, we call 1 epoch
2. Just as I did, randomly sample positive data, when the total amount of sampled data is the same size as the dataset, we call 1 epoch

Which one is right? or which one is commonly used? or which one is better?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, an epoch is when you passed through the whole training data once. and I think in the paper also they mean a pass through the whole training set when they mention an epoch.

However, the epoch can be also defined as after processing **k** elements, where **k** can be smaller than **n** (the size of the training set). Such a definition might make sense when you want to capture get some evaluation about your model on the dev set, and you normally do it after `every single epoch`.

After all, that is my opinion and my understandings of GAN papers.

Good luck!